# URL fetch failure -403 error on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am running Train text classification models with TFLite Model Maker.ipynb on google colab. But when i am running following command in notebook to download dataset;

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
  fname='SST-2.zip',
  origin='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mtl-sentence-representations.appspot.com/o/data%2FSST-2.zip?alt=media&token=aabc5f6b-e466-44a2-b9b4-cf6337f84ac8',
  extract=True)
```

data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(data_dir), 'SST-2')

I am getting 403 error;

Exception: URL fetch failure on https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mtl-sentence-representations.appspot.com/o/data%2FSST-2.zip?alt=media&token=aabc5f6b-e466-44a2-b9b4-cf6337f84ac8: 403 -- Forbidden

Comment: Visiting the URL using a browser results in the same error so the code is doing the best it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code I think it is Stanford Sentiment Treebank v2 (SST2) dataset. Try https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/glue/data/SST-2.zip as origin and see. I got that link from [Model Maker Text Classification Tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/tutorials/model_maker_text_classification.ipynb) by TensorFlow.